# how to solve error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Files' in django 2.0.2

Tags: python-3.x, django-views

Unable to retrieve files from the request in Django. While trying to upload image and icon, and trying to retrieve it in the views, getting 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Files' in django 2.0.2.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import products
from django.utils import timezone

def home(request):
    return render(request,'products/home.html')

@login_required    
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['title'] and request.POST['body'] and request.POST['url'] and request.Files['image'] and request.Files['icon']:
           product = products()
           product.title = request.POST['title']
           product.body =  request.POST['body']
           if request.POST['url'].startswith('http://') or request.POST['url'].startswith('https://'):
               product.url = request.POST['url']
           else:
               product.url = 'http://' + request.POST['url']

           product.image = request.Files['icon']
           product.icon = request.Files['image']
           product.date_pretty = timezone.datetime.now()
           product.hunter = request.User
           product.save()
           return redirect('home')


        else:
           return render(request,'products/create.html',{'error':'Please Fill all the Fields'})
    else:       
        return render(request,'products/create.html')
```

Comment: Provide request params and the method handling the request.

Comment: here,,i uploaded the code from my views.py

Answer (score 0):

I recon, you need to call `request.FILES` instead of `request.Files` to access the files. Check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES).

Comment: thanks a lot sir..finally solved..was writing Files..as u said i changed it to FILES and it is solved now..